# Access checkbox element in my form with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, struts

I have the (struts generated) HTML code:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" class="search" method="get" action="facturable/list.action" name="list" id="list">

<div class="fieldset_medium_right">
                            <div class="label">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="list_allSo" value="true" name="allSo">
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="__checkbox_allSo" id="__checkbox_list_allSo"> 

                            </div>
                            <div label""="" class="">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="list_allEnt" value="true" name="allEnt">
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="__checkbox_allEnt" id="__checkbox_list_allEnt"> 

                            </div>
                            <div label""="" class="">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="list_allUA" value="true" name="allUA">
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="__checkbox_allUA" id="__checkbox_list_allUA"> 

                            </div>
                        </div>

</form>
```

Before my checkboxes were out of the form, I could access them using:
$('#__checkbox_allUA')
                                            .click(
                                                    function() {

Now that they are in the form I can't figure out how to access them.
I have tried things like form.__checkbox_allUA or form.element('__checkbox_allUA') without success.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Since you are referencing them using ID, $('#_checkbox_allUA') will still work. I am sure there is some other issue with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the HTML you posted, let's take the sample below for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="list_allUA" value="true" name="allUA"> 
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="__checkbox_allUA" id="__checkbox_list_allUA">
```

Here is how to select each of the elements:

```
$('#list_allUA').....// the checkbox
$('#__checkbox_list_allUA').... // the associated HIDDEN value
```

Quite likely, you do not need to attach an event handler to the `hidden` element but you might want to do so to the `checkbox`:

```
$('#list_allUA').click( function() { .... });
```

Or, if the checkbox is being dynamically added:

```
$(document).on('click', '#list_allUA', function() { ....... });
```

Comment: so dumb.. Of course, Iwas using the id of the hidden field... Thanks for pointing that to me :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) Feel free to accept this answer. Enjoy.